# iPhone PayPal init failed

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, paypal

I try to init PayPal in my app. Sometimes I get "Network Timeout" error and if I retry to init PayPal this alerts appear again and again. How to avoid this? How to reinit PayPal correctly?  My code is:

```
- (void)initializePayPal {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    [PayPal initializeWithAppID:PP_APP_ID forEnvironment:ENV_SANDBOX];

    while ([PayPal initializationStatus] == STATUS_INPROGRESS) {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
    }

    switch ([PayPal initializationStatus] ) {
        case STATUS_COMPLETED_SUCCESS:
            NSLog(@"STATUS_COMPLETED_SUCCESS");
            break;
        case STATUS_COMPLETED_ERROR: {
            NSDictionary *responseMessage = [PayPal getInstance].responseMessage;
            NSLog(@"STATUS_COMPLETED_ERROR:%@", responseMessage);

            if ([[responseMessage objectForKey:@"errorId"] integerValue] == 10818) {
                [self initializePayPal];
            }
        }
            break;    
        default:
            break;
    }

    [pool release];
}
```

Comment: Why is this done on a separate thread ?

Comment: My problev is not about thread. Do you know how to reinit PayPal if it failed?

Answer (score 1):

PayPal init failed sometimes when i use ENV_SANDBOX The problem was solved when i start use ENV_LIVE instead ENV_SANDBOX

Answer (score 0):

In fact, your program will never work.

```
PayPal.initializePayPal
```

is an async method and the do-initialize part of it has to be run in a message loop. So in your code you while statement are holding the main thread from return to the event loop. what you need to do, is to left this method go and try to test the status when you want to use any of the PayPal feature in your UI. Give the real initialize a chance to run.

Comment: I use a separate thread `[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(initializePayPal) toTarget:self withObject:nil];` to run initialization