# Is initialization of PayPal's MPL library on iOS actually a blocking procedure?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, paypal

The documentation for PayPal Mobile Payments Library for iOS [here](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_MPL_Developer_Guide_and_Reference_iPhone.pdf) 
states that you have two options for initializing the library.
 Option 1 is:

> "Initialize the PayPal object on the main thread, when you need it. Initialize the library 
>   each time before you call the getPayButtonWithTarget method. This implementation is 
>   simple because it uses a single-threaded programming model. The initializeWithAppID 
>   call is blocking, so your application waits for the initialization to complete.
>   To use this method, you can use one line of code: 
>   `[PayPal initializeWithAppID:appID];`"

However, whenever I call this function on my main thread, I get back `STATUS_INPROGRESS`. And I have no choice but to manually sleep until the status changes to `STATUS_COMPLETED_SUCCESS.`

What gives?

Answer (score 1):

You can call 

`[PayPal initializeWithAppID:appID]` in the main thread of `ViewController`, but you will have to wait for 2-3 second for `Paypal` to initialize the information before clicking on the button to make payment. (if you use the  example 

`[[PayPal getPayPalInst] getPayButtonWithTarget:self...];` you will see the button intially disabled, only enabled (turn to yellow) after 1-2 s. 
if you want to call the 

`- (IBAction)simplePayment{}` from the mainthread, you will have to create background thread.
similar thread: [iPhone PayPal init failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895456/iphone-paypal-init-failed)

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [PayPal initializeWithAppID:@"APP-80W284485P519543T" forEnvironment:ENV_SANDBOX];
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(checkInitStatusAndPay) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

-(void) checkInitStatusAndPay {


    while (TRUE) {
        PayPalInitializationStatus status = [PayPal initializationStatus];
        NSLog(@"status %u", status);
        if(status == STATUS_COMPLETED_SUCCESS) {

            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(simplePayment:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
            break;
        }
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2];
    }
}

- (IBAction)simplePayment:(id)sender {

.... 
    [[PayPal getPayPalInst] checkoutWithPayment:payment];
}
```